# Performance test for Siebel 8 application - alarmDate error

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, siebel

I'm preparing test for Siebel 8 application, after all manual correlations, my script replays without errors, but run-time viewer return me error (paste below).

```
@0`0`4`2``0`UC`1`Status`Error`SWEC`9`SRN`wChADN5C8eJO2zBtlyWnw8pX7FijYTURlwhBKjeYzZob`0`1`
Errors`0`2`0`Level0`0`ErrMsg`Required in argument 'alarmDate' not supplied for 
'GetAlarms' method in Business Service 'Alarm Manager'(SBL-DAT-00125)
`ErrCode`7667837`0`6`Command Manager`0`3`0`StateToolBar`0`#10`true`#12`true`#24`true`0`0
`StateExToolBar`0`0`0`FlagsToolBar`0`3`0`State`0`#13`false`#11`true`#14`
false`0`3`StateEx`0`1`0`#11`0`Checked`false`0`0`#13`0`0`0`#14`0`0`0`Flags`0`
```

I think it's something with date format, I have tried change something in code(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Saalu_jr/sandbox), but error still occur.
I'm working in Loadrunner 11.52 (Siebel Web protocol), IE8.
Loadrunner code:

```
web_submit_data("start.swe_14",
    "Action=http://{URL}/start.swe",
    "Method=POST",
    "TargetFrame=",
    "RecContentType=text/html",
    "Referer=",
    "Snapshot=t135.inf",
    "Mode=HTML",
    "EncodeAtSign=YES",
    ITEMDATA,
    "Name=SWEC", "Value={Siebel_SWECount}", ENDITEM,
    "Name=SWEMethod", "Value=GetAlarms", ENDITEM,
    "Name=SWERPC", "Value=1", ENDITEM,
    "Name=SWEActiveApplet", "Value=Service Request List Applet - Home Page VAS TST", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=SWECmd", "Value=InvokeMethod", ENDITEM,
    "Name=SRN", "Value={CorrelationParameter}", ENDITEM,
    "Name=SWEIPS", "Value=@0*0*5*0*0*3*0*8*interval4*150013*packUIStrings4*true9*alarmDate9*2/25/20145*SWEJI5*false3*now7*7:45:26", ENDITEM,
    "Name=SWEActiveView", "Value=Home Service Request List View - VAS ARGUS", ENDITEM,
    "Name=SWEService", "Value=Alarm Manager", ENDITEM,
    LAST);
```

Comment: The canonical date format in Siebel is mm/dd/yyyy. Try to add leading `0` to `2/25/2014` date you supply.

Comment: I added 0, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

check the correlated parameter and do manual correlation

instead of sieble automatic corrleation

Answer (score 0):

The siebel version that I'm working with does not include "packUIStrings" in the SWEIPS arg.

Perhaps change the value to one of the followings:

```
Value=@0*0*4*0*0*3*0*8*interval4*15009*alarmDate9*2/25/20145*SWEJI5*false3*now7*7:45:26
Value=@0*0*5*0*0*3*0*8*interval4*15009*alarmDate9*2/25/20145*SWEJI5*false3*now7*7:45:2613*packUIStrings4*true
```

P.S. I am working with Siebel 8.1.1.11.